# NSSecureCoding throw when simply creating SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to create a SCNNode from my .scn (originally a DAE file that I converted to .scn), and when I do so, the console produces the following:

```
[general] NSSecureCoding allowed classes list contains [NSObject class],
which bypasses security by allowing any Objective-C class to be implicitly
decoded. Consider reducing the scope of allowed classes during decoding by
listing only the classes you expect to decode, or a more specific base class
than NSObject.
```

This is the code that causes the throw:

```
if let usrScene = SCNScene(named: "Test.scnassets/Models/player.scn") {
    usr = usrScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "root", recursively: true)!
}
```

The scene graph is as follows: root->player

How can I remove the throw (or should I)? What does it mean in layman's terms?

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same issue:

I never figured out what the throw means, but I did manage to get rid of it with the following code:

```
extension SCNNode {
    convenience init?(daePath: String) {
        self.init()

        guard let scene = SCNScene(named: daePath) else {
            return
        }

        for childNode in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
            addChildNode(childNode)
        }
    }
}
```

Then import like so...

```
usr = SCNNode(daePath: "Test.scnassets/Models/player.dae")
```